# Magento 2 Layered navigation not showing

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

No matter what I did I couldn't get the layered navigation showing. I have several categories with different product attributes, most of them are dropdowns and still no luck.

**Steps I took:**

> 1. The attributes I want to be included in the layered navigation are all dropdowns.
> 2. Filterable with results option is selected.
> 3. Use in Search Results Layered Navigation option is marked as yes.
> 4. all the categories are marked as anchors.
> 5. All my categories are under the default category.
> 6. Tried the luma and the blank theme.
> 7. Re-indexed and flushed the cache several times.

I have various products with different attributes but still no layered navigation block is showing.

Could you please help me with this. Am I missing something or maybe I have a faulty installation.

**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved by itself after upgrading magento 2.3.2.